# How can I auto select the existing data in a Angular Material Checkbox?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angular-material

I want to auto select the Checkbox if it already exists in the model

I tried with the following code

**Controller**

```
$scope.model = {
  items: [{"key":1, "value": "One"},{"key":2, "value": "Two"},{"key":3, 
  "value": "Three"},{"key":4, "value": "Four"},{"key":5, "value": "Five"}]
};
   $scope.selected = [{"key":2, "value": "Two"},{"key":5, "value": "Five"}];
   $scope.toggle = function(item, list) {
    var idx = list.indexOf(item);
    if (idx > -1) {
        list.splice(idx, 1);
    } else {
        list.push(item);
    }
};

$scope.exists = function(item, list) {
    return list.indexOf(item) > -1;
};
```

**HTML**

```
<div flex="25" ng-repeat="item model.items">
    <md-checkbox  ng-checked="exists(item, selected)" 
        ng-click="toggle(item, selected)">
    {{ item.value }} 
    </md-checkbox>
</div>
```

But the checkbox for Key '2' and '5' not selected by default.

If I replace the following code,

```
$scope.exists = function (item, list) {
 for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i].key === item.key) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

It selects 2 and 5 while page loading but not able un check both. Other 1,3 and 4 works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution off the top of my head

```
<div flex="25" ng-repeat="item model.items">
    <md-checkbox  ng-model="item.selected" 
        ng-click="toggle(item, selected)">
    {{ item.value }} 
    </md-checkbox>
</div>
```

so use ng-model and to set default

```
$scope.model = {
  items: [{"key":1, "value": "One"},{"key":2, "value": "Two", selected: true},{"key":3, 
  "value": "Three"},{"key":4, "value": "Four"},{"key":5, "value": "Five", selected: true}]
};
```

later to get a selected items you just need to use

```
$scope.model.items.filter(function(item){return item.selected});
```

Comment: Thanks Tratto....Actually I will get data for "items" from the server. Is it required to modify it by adding "Selected: true"?.

Comment: Suppose if I add "selected" as you suggested, when I try to save the data my $scope.model.items will look like [{"key":2, "value": "Two", selected: true},{"key":5, "value": "Five", selected: true}] ?

Comment: If yes, then it will fail when I try to save the same in the server side

Comment: Hi Prince, in the original post you did not mention that data is being received from a server, so yes, it will not work. 
I have noticed that you are trying to use indexOf over the array of objects, try to store only 'key' field value and validate it
`ng-click="toggle(item.key, selected)"` and `ng-checked="exists(item.key, selected)"`
and so the default selection array will look like
`$scope.selected=[2,5]`

You original method does not work because of the objects identity, so 
{} == {} returns 'false'

Comment: if you want to use objects instead of keys to simplify communication between client and a server you can use this one https://jsfiddle.net/u25crjj1/2/

Comment: Code in the jsfiddle 1/2 not works. Not able to unselect. But my case is working with this ng-click="toggle(item.key, selected)" and ng-checked="exists(item.key, selected).

Comment: Then I filtered model array based on the keys in the selected array. Great!!! Thanks

Comment: yes, I have noticed this issue with unselect, here is a working version https://jsfiddle.net/u25crjj1/3/

Comment: since ng-repeat creates a private scope passing of "select" to the methods will not work